# Use Secret inside ARM Object

Tags: azure-rm-template

Is there a way of using a secret inside an object?

So I have an object like this that is a parameter to a template

```
{
  "Name": "$(ids)",
  "appSettings": {
    "CertificateOptions__CertificatePath": "$(certificatePath)",
    "CertificateOptions__CertificatePassword": "$(certificatePassword)"
  }
}
```

If certificatePassword is marked as a secret variable, this will not work.

I've tried marking the parameter as a secure object but it seems to make no difference.

I can get this working by downloading the secrets from a keyvault first but I wonder whether the above is possible and I'm missing some sort of setting

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this for `certificatePassword`:

```
"parameters": {
     "certificatePassword": {
         "type": "securestring",
         "metadata": {
             "description": "The value of the certificate password."
         }
     }
}
```

For your reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/template-best-practices#security-recommendations-for-parameters

https://devkimchi.com/2019/04/24/6-ways-passing-secrets-to-arm-templates/